# How to configure routing correctly to allow multiple posts to same MVC controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am having difficulty understanding how to configure routing correctly. I have an MVC application and under one homecontroller I would prefer to have to different post actions.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Login")]
    public ActionResult Login(Login login, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
         return Json(true)
     }

    [HttpPost]
    [ActionName("Locations")]
    public ActionResult Locations(Login login, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
```

In my view I have couple of ajax posts, and I would like them to go to those different action results.

```
           $.ajax({
                ur: '@Url.Action("Locations", "Home")',
                type: 'post',
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                        });
                }
            });

           $.ajax({
                ur: '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")',
                type: 'post',
                data: jsonData,
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (result) {
                        });
                }
            });
```

**The problem is that either one of the ajax posts takes the code to execute under Login action**. This is the maproute I have in routeconfig file, and I think the problem is here.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I am not sure how to modify the maproute for my post to go to appropriate actions.

Thank you.

Comment: What specifically is the problem ? Are you getting any errors ? Also your Location action method does not have any param. then why are you sending data from your ajax call ? Also if you specify contenttype as `application/json`, you should send data as `data: JSON.stringify(jsonData)`

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make the problem clearer. I did post a different version of locations action. I have an object that I send, and it's the same with exception of some additional data.

Comment: So are you saying you are getting 404 for the network calls  ? What is the specific problem you are having ?

Comment: No, what I mean is that every post from both of my ajax calls execute code from Login action, it just does not go to other action. My ajax post to Locations action does not get to that action under controller. In summary, I am trying to have two different posts execute under same controller but different actions.

Comment: Try putting the following before your routes.MapRoute. routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); It's probably an issues with your .NET routing. I use a decorator like the following [Route("SomeRoute"), HttpPost]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
[Route("home/login")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Locations(Login login, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }

[Route("home/locations")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Locations(Login login, FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        return Json(true);
    }
```

and, RouteConfig.cs:

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "SinglePage",
            url: "{Url}",
            defaults: new { Url = "/" }
            );
    }
```

and use:

```
       $.ajax({
            ur: '../../../../../../../../../../home/login',
            type: 'post',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                    });
            }
        });
        $.ajax({
            ur: '../../../../../../../../../../home/locations',
            type: 'post',
            data: jsonData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (result) {
                    });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll pick your answer. It's better for me, as it doesn't use explicit routing.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me this time around is to specify explicit bindings to "[action]/[controller]". Like this:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ProcessLogin",
            url: "Home/ProcessLogin");

        routes.MapRoute(name: "Locations", url: "Home/Locations");
```

To be even more prcesize, just separating ProcessLogin  from the main Login view/action seemed to work good.